# Is ExpressVPN using hidden trackers or spyware?

Tags: malware, vpn, spyware

I have ExpressVPN installed and keep getting strange warnings from Malwarebytes anti-malware.

First odd fact is that XVPND.exe is always running, even after a reboot. I have set ExpressVPN to not auto start at boot. There is no systray icon whatsoever. So first of all, does anyone have any clue why that file is running and listening on port 2015 (TCP)?

Second I keep getting warnings from Malwarebytes anti-malware that XVPND.exe connects to malicious IP-adresses (e.g. 199.19.94.101). When looking up that IP it seems to belong to a Canadian e-commerce service: Yesup Ecommerce Solutions Inc.

I would like to monitor the .exe to see what other connections it makes, any suggestions on how to (on Windows)?

Comment: While we appreciate your concern, this is off-topic here. This is either a question for ExpressVPN support or for SuperUser.

Comment: @schroeder just to make it clear, you mean questions about spyware are off topic on this site? I don't personally care and not active here, just wondering.

Comment: @ShadowWizard questions of the type "this commercial product is behaving unexpectedly - why?" is a question for the vendor's support. This stance is justified by the vendor's support showing up below and answering the question. Because it is closed source, we can only guess. The vendor knows. Even if they are lying, they are the ones who will have facts. Not us.

Answer (score 10):

I work for ExpressVPN. No, this is not malware. Here’s what’s happening:

1. The ExpressVPN app for Windows is composed of two parts: the UI and
   the “engine”. The UI runs as a regular Windows app. The engine
   (xvpnd.exe) runs as a Windows service and is responsible for
   controlling the VPN. One benefit of this design is that the VPN is
   not affected if the app crashes, and that the VPN killswitch can
   start as early as possible on boot.
2. The app and engine communicate with each other using http. That’s why you see the engine listening on port 2015. Important: the engine binds to the local network only. No outside traffic can reach that port.
3. When the user connects to the VPN, the engine is responsible for testing which of our VPN endpoints is likely to give the most reliable and fastest VPN connection. It does that by sending UDP packets to various VPN server IP addresses. The IP you mentioned (199.19.94.101) belongs to our “Canada - Toronto” VPN server location.
4. It’s possible you encountered a bug here. The engine is only supposed to test VPN servers when you’re about to connect to a location, and it seems what you’ve reproduced is a case where the engine was testing VPN servers regardless. Our team is investigating and will fix once we determine the root cause. Thanks for raising the issue.
5. We ourselves haven't been able to reproduce the warning yet in Malwarebytes, however we will contact them for further information. In the meantime you can add an exclusion for ExpressVPN by following these steps: https://support.malwarebytes.org/customer/portal/articles/1835329-how-do-i-stop-malwarebytes-anti-malware-from-blocking-scanning-a-file-or-program-that-i-trust-?b_id=6438

Comment: Problem seems to continue. Today (and few days ago) another warning. Same story. Wondering if it connects to even more servers? Cant think of a reason why the canadian servers is choosen either, I'm in europe.

Comment: if you had deleted the expressvpn parts I'm pretty sure it would have surfaced as a different name. thats what the malware does now. you can spot it with irregularities in process explorer.